# Best way to handle synchronization within Powershell Cmdlets

Tags: c#, powershell, threadpool

As an experiment, I have been writing a cmdlet in C# which makes use of a SystemFileWatcher. As you know, the SystemFileWatcher will call a delegate when a changed event occurs. I would like to send messages back to the user from the delegate. Specifically, I would like to call WriteProgress.

Unfortunately, WriteProgress and, indeed, all other Write* methods will throw an exception if called from a thread other than the "pipeline thread". Further, Powershell doesn't seem to provide a SynchronizationContext, so I'm not sure how to marshal my delgates back to the correct thread.

It seems to me that, since Powershell requires GUI actions to execute on a particular thread, the framework should provide a way to marshal back to that thread. What am I missing? Is there an easier way to synchronize threads in my cmdlets? Is there a reason Powershell opted to use the ThreadPool based SynchronizationContext despite its Write* commands requiring the equivalent of a GUI thread?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am currently attempting to run some long tasks async in my binary cmdlet. I simply wait for all results before calling `WriteObject` etc. I really want to use `ContinueWith` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some luck in setting `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace.DefaultRunspace` before my PS code runs. (I did this for Powershell running as a WCF server).

Suggest you look at this [blog](http://csharpening.net/?p=441), which shows setting the DefaultRunspace from C# before invoking a PS script, which is where I got the idea for my WCF server.